# Batch export OBJ files from Photoshop keeping the PSD filename

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, script

I have an action that takes a psd with a 3d layer
that:

- Resets the rotation of the Object
- Moves it to the Ground Plane
- Unifies it
- Exports to an obj file (here lies the problem)
- Closes the document

When it exports during the batch it writes it as whatever the original file was named overwriting the original.  I want to simply export the obj with whatever name the current psd has.  I have a render action that renders the 3d image and saves it as a jpg that runs just fine so it's probably some problem with ps's export 3d layer command and actions.

I also tried writing a folder action on the mac that will copy and rename the files to a different folder via a bash script pulling names from a txt file and deleting them as it moves them and it sometimes manages to get 2 of the 3 into the destination other times it moves the mtl file as well which was nowhere in it's commands.

```
NAME=$(head -1 /Users/username/Desktop/test.txt)
mv /Users/username/Desktop/3D/OBJ/Run/CH098.obj /Users/username/Desktop/3D/OBJ/Processed/$NAME.obj
tail -n +2 /Users/username/Desktop/test.txt > /Users/username/Desktop/test.bak.txt
mv /Users/username/Desktop/test.bak.txt /Users/username/Desktop/test.txt
```

I then decided it was running too soon and added a 5 second pause before it moved the file to hopefully make sure photoshop had finished writing to the file. (it didn't work)